# Multiple overflow warnings when using scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to implement the following function in Python:

[image]

[image]

And `r >= 0`. And the code is:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

def integrand(n, u, r):
    return norm.pdf(u, 0, 1) * ((norm.cdf(u + r, 0, 1) - 
                                 norm.cdf(u, 0, 1)) ** (n - 2)) * norm.pdf(u + r, 0, 1)

def fRn(n, r):
    return n * (n - 1) * integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(n, r))[0]
```

But the result for `fRn(2, 1)` is:

```
__main__:14: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
__main__:17: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
Out[56]: nan
```

I cannot find how to deal with this error. I would appreciate any help.
Thank.

---

### Second approach

I have tried the following way:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math
import numpy as np


def phi(x):
    return (1/math.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-x**2/2)

def PHI(x):
    return (1.0 + math.erf(x / math.sqrt(2.0))) / 2.0

def integrand(n, u, r):
    return phi(u) * ((PHI(u+r) - PHI(u))**(n-2)) * phi(u+r)


def fRn(n, r):
    return n * (n - 1) * quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(n, r))
```

And, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15576/4053151620.py", line 1, in <module>
    fRn(2,0.1)

  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Simulation\Task_2.py", line 24, in fRn
    return quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(n, r))

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
    points)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 465, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Simulation\Task_2.py", line 20, in integrand
    return phi(u) * ((PHI(u+r) - PHI(u))**(n-2)) * phi(u+r)

OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Would you consider using `sympy`? This problem would be way easier using `sympy`.

Comment: @MSH Could you please help me with that? I have not work with ```sympy``` so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integration variable should be the first argument, the addtional args `(n, r)` will be passed after it, so your integrand function should be defined as

```py
def integrand(u, n, r):
    return norm.pdf(u, 0, 1) * ((norm.cdf(u + r, 0, 1) - 
                                 norm.cdf(u, 0, 1)) ** (n - 2)
                             ) * norm.pdf(u + r, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. This correction solved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer please (check the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you need)